# re: Wifi connection issues

Tags: macbook

I am running Ubuntu 18 and it seems the only way I can connect to the wifi is by using the usb tethering on my cell phone. However, I have a router that I am trying to setup on the device, but it refuses to connect even with the correct password. Here is a bit about my computer....its an early 2008 macbook pro. So any help you all could give me is appreciated! And I can answer any questions too.

Thanks,
Jesse

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Ok My question is why is it that Ubuntu 18 can ernect to my phone's bluetooth thethering/usb thethering feature, but cannot connect to my router with the correct security and password?

Comment: It depends on the drivers. While your computer probably has drivers for USB tethering, it clearly does not have an appropriate driver to connect to Wifi. By the way, there is no Ubuntu 18. It’s either 18.04, 18.10 (outdated) or Ubuntu Core 18. See [Always use full Ubuntu version numbers (if you want to specify the version)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17941/always-use-full-ubuntu-version-numbers-if-you-want-to-specify-the-version)

Comment: I asked to provide information that wiuld help to install dirvers for your wifi, but you ignored that. I am voting to close the question as needing more details.